# Make a Fortran subroutine with save openmp thread safe

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am using netlib LSODAR subroutine to integrate ODE. Codes for which are [available](https://www.netlib.org/odepack/). The code is in F77 and uses save statements and DATA constructs. I can't just remove them and the code is very long to go through and edit with alternatives for each. My code needs to run multiple of these integrations and hence I want to use openmp to parallelize the code. Is there any way to make these code thread-safe? I have made all the functions and subroutines recursive and made all the input variables to the subroutines private/firstprivate but it did not help. Any help is appreciated. If there are any other alternatives which are thread-safe that would be fine too.

A sample would be

```
program main
  !$omp parallel
     call counter()
     call counter()
  !$omp end parallel
end program main

subroutine counter()
 integer i
 save i
 i = i+1
end subroutine counter
```

I can't meddle with the save statements and there are some common blocks as well. In my ideal case the i should be 2 in each thread at the end. but, in this case, it would just lead to (number of processors)*2.

Comment: Could you please give the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer the question without an actual example of what you want to achieve and how the parallelization is supposed to look like.

I can give a general hint to look at the OpenMP constructs to privatize data.  In your particular case, you want to privatize global data and so you will need the `threadprivate` directive (Section 2.19.2 in the OpenMP API 5.0 Specification) and the `copyin`/`copyout` directives (Section 2.19.6).

EDIT:
With the code exmaple added, you can make the code thread-safe by adding an `atomic` directive to the code:

```
subroutine counter()
 integer i
 save i
!$omp atomic
 i = i+1
!$omp end atomic
end subroutine counter
```

This will make sure that all threads will update the single copy of the variable without race conditions.

If you instead want one copy of the variable by thread, then you will have to do this:

```
subroutine counter()
 integer i
 save i
!$omp threadprivate(i)
 i = i+1
end subroutine counter
```

You can then use `copyin` and `copyout` to move values into the thread-private copy of `i`.